# What is wrong with this SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT tblBooks.bookID,
    tblBooks.title,
    tblBooks.author,
    tblBooks.coverImage,
    ROUND(ROUND(tblReviews.rating * 2) / 2, 1) AS rating
FROM tblBooks
    LEFT JOIN tblReviews
        ON tblBooks.bookID = tblReviews.bookID
        LEFT JOIN tblMembers
            ON tblReviews.userID = tblMembers.userID
WHERE tblReviews.bookID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 0, 40
```

I would like to query the database and return the average rating, so if a book has been reviewed 6 times, total up each rating from the 6 users and calculate the average. Right now only the latest rating is being returned. When I change this line to:

```
ROUND(ROUND(AVG(tblReviews.rating) * 2) / 2, 1) AS rating
```

only one result is returned in total so there is obviously something wrong but I have no idea what.

If anyone can shed any light on this, I think it will have something to do with my joins.

Comment: You can't mix aggregate functions and normal column selects. You need to group to get that result or use a subquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `group by` like this:

```
SELECT tblBooks.bookID, tblBooks.title, tblBooks.author, tblBooks.coverImage,
       AVG(tblReviews.rating) as avgRating
FROM tblBooks
     LEFT JOIN tblReviews
     ON tblBooks.bookID = tblReviews.bookID
WHERE tblReviews.bookID IS NOT NULL
group by tblBooks.bookID, tblBooks.title, tblBooks.author, tblBooks.coverImage
ORDER BY avgrating DESC
```

Your query doesn't seem to use any information from the Members table, so I eliminated it.  It is not even filtering based on it, because you are using `left join`.

Comment: I was pulling info from members table in another query, i.e. who had reviewed it. But thanks for pointing that out now.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `AVG` instead?

```
SELECT tblBooks.bookID,
    tblBooks.title,
    tblBooks.author,
    tblBooks.coverImage,
    AVG(tblReviews.rating) AS rating
FROM tblBooks
    LEFT JOIN tblReviews
        ON tblBooks.bookID = tblReviews.bookID
        LEFT JOIN tblMembers
            ON tblReviews.userID = tblMembers.userID
WHERE tblReviews.bookID IS NOT NULL
Group By tblBooks.bookID, tblBooks.title, tblBooks.author, tblBooks.coverImage
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 0, 40
```

## FYI

In MYSQL, you don't need to group by *all* columns all though it's a good practice because you will need to when using other RDMS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `WHERE` either. You are essentially doing an `INNER` join:

```
SELECT t.bookID,
       t.title,
       t.author,
       t.coverImage,
       AVG(r.rating) AS rating
FROM tblBooks AS t
    JOIN tblReviews AS r
        ON b.bookID = r.bookID
GROUP BY t.bookID
--     , t.title, t.author, t.coverImage 
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 40 ;
```

Note: Using only `GROUP BY t.bookID` (and no other columns there) will give correct results only if `bookID` is the primary key (or has a unique constraint) in `tblBooks`. All other DBMS do not allow this (except Postgres but that product has implemented the feature correctly and it does check if the other columns depend on the grouping columns). MySQL does no check at all, so it can give erroneous results in many cases.

It also depends on the `sql_mode` settings, whether the above will run without error.

---

You could alternatively, first group by and then join. This is valid SQL and no error results will be possible:

```
SELECT t.bookID,
       t.title,
       t.author,
       t.coverImage,
       g.rating
FROM tblBooks AS t
    JOIN 
        ( SELECT r.bookID,
                 AVG(r.rating) AS rating
          FROM tblReviews AS r
          GROUP BY r.bookID
        ) AS g
        ON b.bookID = r.bookID
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 40 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing is

```
 GROUP BY tblBooks.bookID, tblBooks.title, tblBooks.author, etc...
```

AVG is an aggregate function that sums out data, use GROUP BY to create groups of aggregates.

Comment: Where would the group by go?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
WHERE tblReviews.bookID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY tblBooks.bookID
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 0, 40
```

Cheers.

Comment: Because if you group by 1 column you can't select the others that are not in the group. Well, MySQL allows that with unexpected results.

Comment: @juergend The results would not be unexpected in this case. he is grouping by the PK of that table and only showing columns of that table.

Comment: Well mate, 1 individual book (with a unique ID), will have _1_ title, _1_ author etc... if that resolves it I'd appreciate a reversal.

Comment: He is selecting multiple fields, he should never group by only one of them even if mysql is stupid enought to allow it. You wil sometimes get the wrong answers this way and thus it is a terrible thing to recommend. You will get more consistent results using the standard group by process of grouping by all non-aggregated fields.

Comment: @d'alar'cop, books often have multiple authors.

Comment: @HLGEM: Come on, they could have multiple authors, but not in this specific table design.

Comment: Would you really want the average rating to GROUP on the authors? - I agree that some DBMSs will not like aggregating like this... and he can use XML_AGGREGATE to solve the multiple authors issue maybe.

Comment: @ypercube yes, they have made a bigger assumption than I have.

Comment: Recommending poor practices is an automatic downvote from anyone who knows why they are poor. You are supposed to be teaching the correct method not one that is poorly implemented and can often result in wrong results.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the Hidden Columns (mis)feature in MySQL.  However, I don't think using it, especially on a primary key, is worthy of a downvote.  +1 from me.

Comment: ok, fair enough buddy. I just think it's bad form to downvote. cheers to those who constructively contribute.

Comment: @HLGEM Amen to that (*poorly implemented and can often result in wrong results* and *be teaching the correct method*). I don't mind if one uses the hidden columns feature, as long as it is explicitly stated that (and why)  it works in the specific case and that it should be used with extreme care so it doesn't give wrong results.

Comment: @ypercube: I totally agree, but can't find that in the answer.